# How to check if ID of one table is equal to ID of another table, if equal assign new value to another column in the table in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, webforms

I am trying to build a quiz application. I have created two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers] (
       [AID]           INT            NOT NULL,
       [QID]           INT            NOT NULL,
       [Answer]        NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
       [CorrectAnswer] NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AID] ASC),
       CONSTRAINT [FK_Answers_Question] FOREIGN KEY ([QID]) REFERENCES [dbo].         
       [Question] ([QID])
        );

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Question] (
       [QID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
       [Question] NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([QID] ASC)
 );
```

Here, QID is autogenerated and incremented.
The Answer Table contains AID as primary key And QID as foreign key. 
Now my question arises is Should I autogenerate and increment Answers.QID or should I set it separately? And also I want Answers.AID to increment upto 4 (Multiple Choice Question with 4 options).
Something like this :

```
Answers Table                         
 AID | QID | Answer
 1 | 1 | Scripting Language
 2 | 1 | Programming Language
 3 | 1 | MarkUp Language
 4 | 1 | Network Protocol

Question Table
 QID | Question
 1 | What is HTML?
```

So whenever I try to insert answer in the Answer table, it should check if Question.QID = Answers.QID. If true, Assign Answer.AID from 1 to 4 and enter the answer.

All this is managed by Admin, so I have created a Web form AddQuestion.aspx where the question can be added when admin clicks the Add button and it redirects to AddAnswer.aspx where the admin can save and upload the answers.

AddQuestion.aspx

```
public partial class AddQuestion : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlConnection connection;
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheQuizConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string addQuestion = "insert into Question(Question) values(@Ques)";
        command = new SqlCommand(addQuestion, connection);

        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qid", TextBoxQid.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ques", TextBoxQuestion.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("AddAnswer.aspx");

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

AddAnswer.aspx

```
public partial class AddAnswer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     SqlCommand command;
     SqlConnection connection;
     protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        Response.Redirect("AddQuestion.aspx");
     }
     public void CheckQid()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheQuizConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string checkQid = "select count(QID) from Question";
        using (command = new SqlCommand(checkQid, connection))

    }
    protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheQuizConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string addAnswer = "insert into Answers(Answer) values(@Answer)";
        command = new SqlCommand(addAnswer, connection);

        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aid", TextBoxAid.Text);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qid", TextBoxQid.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", TextBoxAnswer.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("AddAnswer.aspx");
    }
}
```

I am new to asp.net and visual studio. I tried to search for answers but could not find anything. I appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: what happens when you run `command.ExecuteNonQuery` any errors ? also where are you executing the actual sql query in this method `public void CheckQid()`

Comment: I'm sure it does with no QID parameter

Comment: @MethodMan I don't to how to write sql query, i just tried this : Update Answers set QID = (Select QID from Question where Question.QID = Answer.QID) But it did not work. And I don't have that much knowledge in sql as well.

Comment: sounds like you should open up chrome and do a google search on Basic SQL Tutorials.. `I don't know is not an excuse` this is why there are things like google.com out there.. good luck

Comment: @MethodMan I have started learning. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

AID cannot be the primary key if it is limited to 1-4. One option would be to make it a composite key consisting of both QID and AID. Another option would be to either add an identity column as the primary key or just not to use one.

If this was my project I would probably just add the PK on a new `IDENTITY`column to the Answer table. Please note that I generally don't do table design that requires constraint checking on INSERT/UPDATE, so there is no FK  and with the exception of the PK all fields allow *null*. The only exception would be if I was using a compound index.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers] (
    AnswerNDX       INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AID]           INT               NULL,
    [QID]           INT               NULL,
    [Answer]        NVARCHAR (200)    NULL,
    [CorrectAnswer] NVARCHAR (200)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Answers_NDX PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnswerNDX] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

And I generally would put the Answer Insert routine into a Stored Procedure. The first part of this procedure declares a variable for your AID defaulting to 1. It then checks to see if this question has an answer already, and if so it gets the Max for AID and adds 1 to it. It will then INSERT the new answer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_QuestionAnswerAdd (
    @qID            INT,
    @Answer         NVARCHAR(200),
    @CorrectAnswer  NVARCHAR(200)
) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @aID INT = 1
    IF EXISTS (SELECT [AID] FROM Answers WHERE (QID = @QID)) BEGIN
        SELECT @aID = Max(AID) + 1 FROM Answers WHERE (QID = @QID)
    END

    INSERT Answers( aID,  qID,  Answer,  CorrectAnswer)
    VALUES        (@aID, @Qid, @Answer, @CorrectAnswer)
END
GO
```

Your C# code for this procedure would be a little different, as we will be calling a stored procedure instead of just passing a text command. You would not assign an AID, as SQL will look it up an increment.

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int RowsAffected;
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TheQuizConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {
        string sqlcmd = "usp_QuestionAnswerAddusp_QuestionAnswerAdd";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@qID", (int)TTextBoxQid.Text);
        cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@Answer", TextBoxAnswer.Text);
        cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@CorrectAnswer", string.Empty); // didnt see a value for this
        try {
            connection.Open();
            RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            RowsAffected = -1;
            // add error handling
        }
        finally { connection.Close(); }
    }
    /*
        RowsAffected should be equal to 1.
        -1 would mean there was an C# exception
        Any other failure would be in SQL commands
    */


    Response.Redirect("AddAnswer.aspx");
}
```

This is by no means a complete example. If you were deleting questions the AID would not reflect that automatically. Or if you wanted to change the order of the answers as AID could also double as an `ORDER BY` factor.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me. Thanks for making me understand as well. Really appreciate.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider up-marking this or answered if it helps